# JS palindrome check with "every" helper method breakdown

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ecmascript-6, palindrome

I'm trying to understand why my input is `falsy`

```
> palindrome('abaasa')
false
```

Given this palindrome checker function

```
function palindrome(str) {
  return str.split('').every((char, i) => {
    return char === str[str.length - i - 1];
  });
}
```

from what I understand the, `every` helper does a boolean check for every value taken in from the array.

When broken down it would look like this to me.

```
(0 => a) === (5 => a) // truthy <--- START
(1 => b) === (4 => s) // falsy
(2 => a) === (3 => a) // truthy
```

I know there is more comparison than necessary, and I'm aware this needs optimization.

Continuing on the iteration, this is where the pointers intersect.

```
(3 => a) === (2 => a) // truthy
(4 => b) === (1 => s) // falsy
(5 => a) === (0 => a) // truthy <--- STOP
```

**Question**

> Is the `every` method smart enough to return false when it finds a
>   falsy comparison?
>
> If not how was the `falsy` return determined given my function?

Comment: `every()` stops iteration on the first comparison that returns `false`. However, you'll spend twice as much time as necessary checking when a string _is_ a palindrome.

Comment: Is the every method smart enough to return false when it finds a falsy comparison?  YES IT IS!!

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I think if `every()` stops iterations on a `false` comparison then the best case is `log(n)` it won't really have to spend twice as much time as necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if it's smart enough by introducing a `console.log` statement inside your `every` function. This will allow you to *actually* see where it stops.

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  return str.split('').every((char, i) => {
    console.log(i);
    return char === str[str.length - i - 1];
  });
}

let str = 'abaasa';
console.log(palindrome(str)); // prints: 0 1 false
```

> Is the every method smart enough to return false when it finds a falsy comparison?

As you can see, **it is** smart enough to stop after a falsy. It only went through the indeces *0 and 1* when it could have reached *5* in total.

Answer (score 1):

The `every()` function is used to do a boolean check on every element in an array.

So if you have:

`const array = [0, 10, 14];`

And the question is you want to know if every value in that array is greater than 5.

You can write some code that looks like this:

`array.every((val) => val > 5);`

We would take the array, call the `every()` function on it and pass in a function to invoke every element on the array. So I passed in `val` and checked to see if 0 is greater than 5 that would return false.

When the `every()` function runs it checks the `return` value of every function run, if any function returns false **then the overall expression returns false as well**, however if it returns true for every element, the entire function expression returns true.

So it returns a comparison for every element in an array.

Keep in mind that you are doing twice as much work by using the `every()` array helper to resolve a palindrome. It is a solution, but it's doing twice as much work than it needs to do.

So the reason yours returned falsey there is because each character is not a mirror image of the character on the other side.

What are you saying here is:

`return char === str[str.length - i - 1];`

return a comparison between the first element and the mirrored element on the other side of the array.

```
[abaasa]

a === a // true
b === s // false
a === a // true
```

There is a false there so it is not a palindrome.

For it to be a palindrome:

```
[abaaba]

a === a // true
b === b // true
a === a // true
```

Answer (score 0):

[.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

is checking whether every condition is true(y). If any of them is evaluated to false, then it will return false. This is what the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) says about its return:

> true if the callback function returns a truthy value for every array
>   element; otherwise, false.